# Dir.glob to process all files recursively and keep track of their parent directory

Tags: ruby, recursion

I wish to process all .jpg files recursively. I need to have their parent directory available at some variable as well. So I moved from:

```
Dir.cwd("/some/path")

Dir.glob("**/*.jpg") { |the_file| }
```

to:

```
Dir.cwd("/some/path")

Dir.glob("**/") { |the_dir|
  Dir.glob("#{the_dir}*.jpg") { |the_file|
    puts "file: #{the_file} is at #{the_dir}"
  }      
}
```

Unfortunately it omits *.jpg files at the `Dir.cwd` itself. For my test dir:

```
$ find  
.
./some_dir
./some_dir/another_one
./some_dir/another_one/sample_A.jpg
./some_dir/sample_S.jpg
./sample_4.jpg
./sample_1.jpg
./sample_3.jpg
./sample_2.jpg
```

I got output for `sample_A.jpg` and `sample_S.jpg` but not for any other.

Comment: Do you need a relative path or would the full path do ?

Comment: After reading your answer I got what you're asking about. Full paths would be better (I don't need `File.basename`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood this should do:

```
Dir.glob("**/*.jpg") do |thefile| 
  puts "#{File.basename(thefile)} is at #{File.dirname(thefile)}"  
end
```

`dirname` give you the parent directory only.

You may extend `dirname` by `expand_path` if you want the full path name.
I.e.: `File.dirname(File.expand_path(thefile))` which should give you the full path to the file.

Side note, there's other methods in ruby > 2.0 from the [File class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/File.html), but I did stick with the basic ones here.

Comment: It works great but I think two loops would be just better in my case (I have a lot files in every dir so it would be better to don't call `File.dirname` for each). I would appreciate if you can propose solution with two loops.

Comment: `dirname` isn't directly replaceable by `expand_path`. The first removes the final entry (file or directory) and `expand_path` modifies the path to remove macros and redundant relative movements.

Comment: Indeed, I should have said add instead, updating the answer

Comment: @pawel7318 just back to home, I'll have a look a it tomorrow if no-one else answered before ;) (but something along your actual loop + one on *.jpg should do in this case, else it need a recursive method, I'm unsure it will be really slowest calling dirname and expend_path, to be tested)

Comment: @theTinMan do you find it better now ?

Comment: It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I found one other way with two loops which I believe can be faster in some situations as it doesn't call `File.dirname` for each file:

```
Dir.glob("{./,**/}") { |the_dir|
  # puts "dir: #{the_dir}"

  Dir.glob("#{the_dir}*.jpg") { |the_file|
    puts "file: #{the_file} is at #{the_dir}"
  }      
}
```

Comment: I had an idea in the night: using regex to split the file name and get what is before the last `/`: `the_file[/^(.*)\/(.*)$/,1]` No idea if it would be faster or not.

Comment: This won't be faster. You're using two directory listings where one would suffice. The inner one is going to add time, not subtract it.

Comment: @Tensibai, using regex will not be an improvement. File's `dirname`, `basename`, and `split` are written in C specifically for this and would be simpler, less error prone, and faster.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for the confirmation, it was what I though by logic, but I've no reference and not enough expertise in ruby to affirm it :) that's why I say I've no idea on the speed, and I did not had time to make test about it to give facts ;)

Comment: It's not really a Ruby issue. It's using built-in functionality vs. trying to use Regex, which *can* do it but isn't optimized for it. The OS supplies the necessary code to tear apart a path, and Ruby, like any other decent language, will take advantage of the existing tools.

Comment: @theTinMan I do agree, even if it's not On code,  a compiled code (C or other) will be faster than interpreted language anyway ;)

Comment: It *should* be faster. Poorly written compiled code can be bested by well written interpreted code, especially if memory management or buffering is misused/abused.

Comment: I strongly believe that if there is 1000 folders and each of it contains 10K files than it'll be better to assign `the_dir` 1000 times rather than 10M times. BTW: Finally I switched to one-loop solution because of some other issues (I would have to do special case for `./` to get it's `File.dirname` which I just don't like to do. I like Ruby for it's simplicity and I decided to do not sacrifice it.